# Python profile output in eclipse

Tags: python

When I run profiler in eclipse with specifying file name, I expect the output to be dumped in the file in readable format. But I see binary file being created ( even if I specify filename.txt ) which I cannot read.
How do I get the output of the profiler ( profile module ) in a text file ?

python 2.5 version.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pstats` to load the `profile` data (see [the documentation here](http://docs.python.org/library/profile.html))

In related news: you can use [gprof2dot](http://code.google.com/p/jrfonseca/wiki/Gprof2Dot) to turn these stats into fancy graphs ;-)

Comment: so I can never see the information in a file? I will always have to load it?

Comment: You'll need `pstats` to provide you with a human-readable version of the binary data, yes. Isn't too hard since it provides a `print_stats()` function. What exactly is troubling you with having to (temporarily) storing these files somewhere?

Comment: I did not know that after the file is generated by eclipse, I have to load it in python shell to read it. I was expecting it to be in a readable format. But now that I can read , other work around is fine. Like get the python shell output on a text file ( may be copy/paste) to be able to email the output.